# Django filter DateTimeField by TimeField value

Tags: django, django-1.8

I have a `Timeslot` model with `start` and `end` fields of type `DateTimeField`. Another class `Constraint` also has `start` and `end` fields but of type `TimeField`.

I can filter `Constraint` objects by the `start` and `end` values of a given timeslot:

```
Constraint.objects.filter(start=timeslot.start)
```

But now I am in need of filtering `Timeslot` based on the value of a given constraint. The scenario is having multiple timeslots that define different **datetime** ranges throughout a time domain, and I want to select those outside a given **time** range specified by an existing `constraint`:

```
Timeslot.object.filter(Q(end__lte=constraint.start) | Q(start__gte=constranit.end))
```

For example, let's say I have `timeslots` going through October 23rd to October 29th, each day starting at `10am` and ending at `1pm`. The duration would be of `1 hour`, so each day would have 3 timeslots, which totals in 21 timeslots.

```
23 Oct, 10am-1pm (3 timeslots)
24 Oct, 10am-1pm (3 timeslots)
25 Oct, 10am-1pm (3 timeslots)
26 Oct, 10am-1pm (3 timeslots)
27 Oct, 10am-1pm (3 timeslots)
28 Oct, 10am-1pm (3 timeslots)
29 Oct, 10am-1pm (3 timeslots)
```

And a `constraint` that defines the range `11am-12pm`. I would like to select the `timeslots` outside that range. The result would be the timeslots between `10am` and `11am`, and those with a start of `12pm` and an `end` of `1pm`, for each day of course.

I can't do this because it results in a `TypeError`.

Why can I filter `TimeField` based on `DateTimeField` values, but not the opposite? And what's a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.11 you could use the [__time-api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#time) to match the time-part of your timeslot with the time of your constraintmodel like this:

```
Timeslot.objects.filter(Q(end__time__lte=constraint.start)|Q(start__time__gte=constraint.end))
```

If you dont want/can't update your django version you could still use the [__hour and __minute-api](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#hour) for filtering:

```
Timeslot.objects.filter(Q(end__hour__lte=constraint.start.hour,end__minute__lte=constraint.start.minute)|Q(start__hour__gte=constraint.end.hour, start__minute__gte=constraint.end.minute))
```

Additionaly you could think about using [exlude()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exclude) rather than filter() to improve the readability of your code